# Как организовывать скрипты одной/нескольких сущностей?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Представим, что у меня есть игрок(Player) и противник(Enemy). У игрока есть скрипт движения `PlayerMovement` и скрипт анимации `PlayerAnimation`, у противника тоже самое(`EnemyMovement` и `EnemyAnimation`). Но может лучше создать один скрипт `Player` и `Enemy`, а уже в них создать классы `PlayerMovement`, `PlayerAnimation` и `EnemyMovement`, `EnemyAnimation`, а классы `Player` и `Enemy` будут базовыми классами, хранящие поля и свойства? Но такой скрипт будет громоздким и он будет плохо читаться. Так вот, как лучше сделать?

Вот пример на коде:

```
public class Player : Monobehaviour
{
    protected float _speed;
    protected string _animation = "SomeAnimation";
}

public class Movement : Player
{ 
    // ...какая-то логика
}

public class Animation : Player
{
    // ...какая-то логика
}
```

Comment: `Movement : Player` и `Animation : Player` - самое банальное нарушение SOLID и наследования. Это всё равно что ребёнок отнаследован от трактора.. Вообще для начала можно писать архитектуру вообще не привязываясь к фреймворкам или движкам. А базовой сущностью может быть Creature у которого есть методе move, hit и пр. Анимацию можно сделать отдельным классом, но не наследовав от Player/Enemy, а который в конструктор принимает Creature и у уже с ним что-то проворачивает.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можете пример кода показать?

Comment: ...Какого кода?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский обычного) класс Creature не очень понятен, в методе Move будет производиться движение или же он будет вызывать другой метод, в котором уже будет логика движения?